# Prove that $ m_{a} \geq m_{g} \geq m_{h} $ using strict inequalities unless $ a = b $.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

$ m_{a} = \frac{1}{2} (a + b) $ 
 
$ m_{g} =  \sqrt{ab} $ 
 
$ \frac{1}{m_{h}} = \frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b})$

Attempted Solution:

I believe I have shown the first step, which is $ m_{a} \geq m_{g} $ but i'm stuck on showing $ m_{g} \geq m_{h} $

$ \frac{a + b}{2} > \sqrt{ab} $ 
$ (\frac{a + b}{2})^2 > (\sqrt{ab})^2 $

$\frac{a^2 + 2ab + b^2}{4} > ab$

$a^2 + 2ab + b^2 > 4ab $ 
$a^2 -2ab + b^2 > 0 $ 
$(a - b)^2 > 0 $

so if $a = b$ we have $(a -b)^2 \geq 0$

Therefore, $m_{a} \geq m_{g} $

Now, i'm not sure if that is correct or not, if not can you please guide me to the complete solution or if I am correct on this part, provide a solution for $m_{g} \geq m_{h} $

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: if you set $c=\frac{1}{a},d=\frac{1}{b}$, then

$$ m_h(a,b)\leq m_g(a,b) $$
is equivalent to:
$$ m_g(c,d) \leq m_a(c,d).$$

Comment: So, if I simply note this fact in the proof, then I can say that $m_{g} \geq m_{h}$ because $ (\frac{1}{a} - \frac{1}{b}) ^2 \geq 0 $ which directly follows from my solution of $m_{a} \geq m_{g}$ ?